# kafka + Best Practices For Apache Kafka Configuration to avoid Sync problem

Tags: apache-kafka

we have 3 Kafka machines with version - 0.1

we seen that some of the topics as - bio_test_covid9_verification
are not balanced and ISR are not sync as the following

```
 Topic: bio_test_covid9_verifcation  Partition: 0    Leader: 1003    Replicas: 1003,1001,1002        Isr: 1003
        Topic: bio_test_covid9_verifcation  Partition: 1    Leader: 1003    Replicas: 1001,1002,1003        Isr: 1003
        Topic: bio_test_covid9_verifcation  Partition: 2    Leader: 1002    Replicas: 1002,1003,1001        Isr: 1003,1002,1001
        Topic: bio_test_covid9_verifcation  Partition: 3    Leader: 1003    Replicas: 1003,1002,1001        Isr: 1003
        Topic: bio_test_covid9_verifcation  Partition: 4    Leader: 1003    Replicas: 1001,1003,1002        Isr: 1003
        Topic: bio_test_covid9_verifcation  Partition: 5    Leader: 1002    Replicas: 1002,1001,1003        Isr: 1003,1002,1001
        Topic: bio_test_covid9_verifcation  Partition: 6    Leader: 1003    Replicas: 1003,1001,1002        Isr: 1003
        Topic: bio_test_covid9_verifcation  Partition: 7    Leader: 1003    Replicas: 1001,1002,1003        Isr: 1003
        Topic: bio_test_covid9_verifcation  Partition: 8    Leader: 1002    Replicas: 1002,1003,1001        Isr: 1003,1002,1001
        Topic: bio_test_covid9_verifcation  Partition: 9    Leader: 1003    Replicas: 1003,1002,1001        Isr: 1003
        Topic: bio_test_covid9_verifcation  Partition: 10   Leader: 1003    Replicas: 1001,1003,1002        Isr: 1003
        Topic: bio_test_covid9_verifcation  Partition: 11   Leader: 1002    Replicas: 1002,1001,1003        Isr: 1003,1002,1001
```

What is expected should be like this

```
 Topic: bio_test_covid9_verifcation  Partition: 0    Leader: 1003    Replicas: 1003,1001,1002        Isr: 1003
        Topic: bio_test_covid9_verifcation  Partition: 1    Leader: 1001    Replicas: 1001,1002,1003        Isr: 1003,1002,1001
        Topic: bio_test_covid9_verifcation  Partition: 2    Leader: 1002    Replicas: 1002,1003,1001        Isr: 1003,1002,1001
        Topic: bio_test_covid9_verifcation  Partition: 3    Leader: 1003    Replicas: 1003,1002,1001        Isr: 1003,1002,1001
        Topic: bio_test_covid9_verifcation  Partition: 4    Leader: 1001    Replicas: 1001,1003,1002        Isr: 1003,1002,1001
        Topic: bio_test_covid9_verifcation  Partition: 5    Leader: 1002    Replicas: 1002,1001,1003        Isr: 1003,1002,1001
        Topic: bio_test_covid9_verifcation  Partition: 6    Leader: 1003    Replicas: 1003,1001,1002        Isr: 1003,1002,1001
        Topic: bio_test_covid9_verifcation  Partition: 7    Leader: 1001    Replicas: 1001,1002,1003        Isr: 1003,1002,1001
        Topic: bio_test_covid9_verifcation  Partition: 8    Leader: 1002    Replicas: 1002,1003,1001        Isr: 1003,1002,1001
        Topic: bio_test_covid9_verifcation  Partition: 9    Leader: 1003    Replicas: 1003,1002,1001        Isr: 1003,1002,1001
        Topic: bio_test_covid9_verifcation  Partition: 10   Leader: 1001    Replicas: 1001,1003,1002        Isr: 1003,1002,1001
        Topic: bio_test_covid9_verifcation  Partition: 11   Leader: 1002    Replicas: 1002,1001,1003        Isr: 1003,1002,1001
```

so in total only 2 topics from 63 topics get bad state that ISR isnt sync and leaders are not balanced

so in order investigate what happening here we first verify some of the Kafka parameters in order top understand if sync problem related to not correct Kafka parameters
and I gives here some of the parameters that are configured

in our Kafka config we have for example

```
    `min.insync.replicas=1`  ( while replication.factor is 3 )
```

as I know `min.insync.replicas` is a config on the broker that denotes the minimum number of in-sync replicas required to exist for a broker to allow
acks=all

so I want to ask if this settings of `min.insync.replicas=1`  , is part of the problem ? and if we set `min.insync.replicas=3` then it will avoid sync ISR problems

what do you thinks?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Sync issues" like down replicas are not a symptom of bad broker configs, rather it indicates that you have other network or hardware failures that cause the brokers to become unhealthy

You should definitely maintain `min.insync.replicas=2` to ensure that losing one broker doesn't lose data. Setting to 3 along with an equal replication factor isn't really best practice

This is stated as such [in Cloudera documentation](https://docs.cloudera.com/documentation/enterprise/6/6.3/topics/kafka_faq.html#concept_g5s_tpl_d2b__section_l5s_tpl_d2b).

Comment: the default in our kafka is min.insync.replicas=1 , do you think we should set it to min.insync.replicas=2  ?

Comment: My answer doesn't say anything different

Comment: in doc I see Disable unclean leader election , which is the parameter that defined it in ambari?

Comment: I've never used Ambari with Kafka, but you should be able to define your own `server.properties` values